# "var variable" returns undefined?

Tags: javascript

When I run "var variable = true;" in chrome console I get "undefined" returned:

```
> var variable = true;
undefined
```

But when I run without "var" it returns true:

```
> variable = true;
true
```

Why is it returning "undefined" with "var"?

It's confusing cause I expected it would return true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first is a statement, while the second is an expression. While not quite the same, it is similar to C's rules:

```
// A statement that has no value.
int x = 5;

// An expression...
x = 10;

// ...that can be passed around.
printf("%d\n", x = 15);
```

Comment: Is it valid js code to use "var variable = true;" or should i run "var variable; variable = true;"?

Comment: @ajsie - it is valid, and both statements are equivalent.

Comment: Yes, it is valid code. You can confirm this by evaluating `variable` after executing the statement.

Answer (score 4):

`var x = y;` is a *statement* which returns no value. In the WebKit JS console, a statement that returns no value will show `undefined` as the result, e.g.

```
> if(1){}
undefined
> ;
undefined
> if(1){4}  // this statement returns values!
4
```

The assignment is an *expression* which returns the value of the LHS. That means, this *expression statement* has a return value, and this will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

An assignation returns the assignation's value, but with `var` this return is "consumed" (?)

Answer (score 1):

Statements always return `undefined`.

```
var color = "red"; 
undefined
```

Expressions always return a value.

```
color = "orange";
"orange"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out, that the answer provided by [kennytm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224671/kennytm) should be the accepted answer, at least for pedagogical purposes. The accepted answer doesn't answer why this is the case or provide deeper understanding.

Like the `null` value in JavaScript, `undefined` indicates absence of value, but in a much deeper way. The following should be taken as complimentary to the above-mentioned answers:

> `undefined` is the value of variables that haven't been initialized and the
>   value you get when you query the value of an object property or
>   array element that doesn't exist. This value is also returned by
>   functions that have no return value, and the value of function
>   parameters for which no argument is supplied. `undefined` is a predefined 
>   global variable (not a language keyword like null) that is initialized
>   to the undefined value.
>
> You might consider `undefined` to represent a system-level, unexpected,
>   or error-like absence of value and `null` to represent program-level,
>   normal, or expected absence of value.
>
> -- Flanagan, David. JavaScript: The Definitive Guide: Activate Your Web
>   Pages (Definitive Guides) . O'Reilly Media. Kindle Edition.

Also, makes sure to check out both the accepted and the second most voted answer for further reference:
[Chrome/Firefox console.log always appends a line saying undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined)