# Chrome/Firefox console.log always appends a line saying 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, debugging, logging, console

Every time `console.log` is executed, a line saying `undefined` is appended to the output log.

It happens in both Firefox and Chrome on Windows and Linux.

Comment: So what is your question? Could you show some example code that produces this? What is the behaviour you expect?

Comment: That's probably not enough information to solve your problem

Comment: I gave it my best shot even though it's indeed lacking some info :)

Comment: `console.log()` returns `undefined`.

Comment: My issue was I was only displaying the _errors_ and _warnings_, displaying the _messages_ and _info_ worked for me.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

If you're running `console.log()` from a JS file, this `undefined` line should not be appended.

If you're running `console.log()` from the console itself, it makes sense. This is why: In the console you can type a name of a variable (for example try typing `window`) and it prints info about it. When you run any void function (like console.log) from the console, it also prints out info about the return value, `undefined` in this case.

I tested both cases on my Chrome (Mac ver 23.0.1271.101) and indeed I see the `undefined` line when I run it inside the console. This `undefined` also appears when I write this line in the console: `var bla = "sdfdfs"`

Comment: Thanks for replying.I'm running it from the console itself, I tried to stop all the extensions , but I get the same result.

Comment: Well, this is the expected behavior. Everything is working as it should. You can enable you extensions back :) Just run console.log from a JS file and you won't see this. Why are you running console.log from the console anyways? You can just type any variables name without console.log

Comment: but it wasn't before , that's why!!

Comment: Maybe your Chrome was updated and this behavior started in newer versions.. Since the same thing happens in my Chrome (on Mac), I highly doubt it's a problem..

Comment: As @Yigit Alparslan said. any method that don't return value like "Console.Log("my message") returns undefined. 
If you check the console you will see that first it print the console log "my message" and than return the console.log return value -> undefined

Answer (score 44):

Although talkol´s answer is ok, I try to put it more straight:

JavaScript is designed as a dynamic language which means that the type (string, void, boolean …) of a function return value is not pre-defined. If a function does not use a return statement or an empty return statement with no value, JavaScript automatically returns undefined. That means that in JavaScript every function returns something, at least undefined.

So the function `console.log()` in Chrome console either uses no or an empty return statement, so that the return value of this function is undefined. This function return value gets also displayed in the Chrome console.

[If somebody know where to find the definition of the `console.log()` function in Google Chrome source code, please comment with the link, then we can even go further and look at the real code, would be nice.]

Sources:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20915524/1744768
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript

Comment: Referencing other posts is fine, but this isn't a full answer so it would fit better as a comment on the answer you are referencing.

Comment: I tried to do that, but I am not able to comment due to lack of enough reputation ("You must have 50 reputation to comment"), so I thought using the "unoptimal" way of answering instead of commenting would be better then not posting.

Comment: That's fair. I can't remove my downvote without you editing the post though. Mind elaborating on what is located at that link in the answer? If you can do that, then I can change my vote :)

Answer (score 18):

Follow the picture to solve this problem:

```
Ctrl + Shift + J
```

[image]

Comment: Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does that image explain what "undefined" means?

Answer (score 9):

Console environment in your browser is designed to take the very last statement expression in a program and evaluate it for a value and then show you that value.

The result of an assignment expression is the value that was assigned. 
So the JavaScript engine just does an assignment but the console does one extra step which is to set whatever my last statement is, give you that value back. That’s why it prints 2:

[image: here.]

In statements that have no return value you get something like undefined.

Comment: Maybe a little bit off-topic but why does `a=2` return 2 and `var b=2` return nothing? (I guess because `=` is an operator that returns a value but why doesn't it do the same in the declaration statement?)

Comment: @Fatima, What is your reference for this answer?

Answer (score 2):

That `undefined` you see in console is the return value of the function:
check out these two variants:

> This one returns nothing

[image]

---

> This one returns something:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is simply create your own console.log like function with a return to change this behavior when doing a lot of coding in the developer console. Here is an example of what that looks like in the developer console:

```
console.log('I hate seeing the next line stating the obvious.')
I hate seeing the next line stating the obvious.
undefined
log = function(l){return l}
function log()
if(1 === 2){console.log('1 is not equal to 2.')}else{log('No Shit Sherlock.')}
"No Shit Sherlock."
```

Answer (score 1):

`undefined` is the return value of the console.log() in Chrome developer tools. You will get undefined if you do the following in Chrome developer tools, and you will see that you get undefined even though x has the value 3.

```js
> let x = 3
> undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember one thing. Any function that has some definition will always return something, If you skip the **return** keyword, it will eventually return undefined when you call it.

Answer (score -2):

In DropDown Section, Click `Info` to see logs.

[image]

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does the screenshot explain why that line says "undefined"?

Answer (score -5):

If you're using `console.log` to emit multiple values in a single line, here's a hacky alternative:

```
var1 + ' ' + var2 + ' ' + var...
```

(Better ideas welcome, this might blow up in certain circumstances)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What does that hack do?