# Iterating array returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a problem here. You see, I have a JSON like:

[image]

All the elements are equals.

The thing is, when I execute this code:

```
var arrayProcesos = data['arrayProcesos'];
for(var k=0, len = arrayProcesos.length; k < len; k++) { //... }
```

The for iterates over the array (6 positions) and then goes to the position 6 (yes, the "7th element", I don't know why because it doesn't exist), and there it returns undefined.

Do you know how it can be possible and how to fix it?

**EDIT:**

Here is the code that returns the "undefined" error:

```
var proceso = arrayProcesos[k];
var nombreProceso = proceso['procesos']['denominacion'];
```

When it try to take ['procesos'], the Console says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'procesos' of undefined"

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code which you posted. Can you post code within for loop?

Comment: Based on the code you provided, it could go out of bounds if `len` is changed somewhere in the body.

Comment: If i set up data as `var data = { arrayProcesos: [
  "zero",
  "one",
  "two",
  "three",
  "four",
  "five"
] }`  then this works fine as the body of the for: `console.log(k, arrayProcesos[k])`

Comment: Why do you think it goes to position 6? What does your loop do? Can you please `console.log(k, len)` after the loop? This sounds like a duplicate of [console.log always appends a line saying undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14633968/1048572) currently

Comment: Try printing `k` like @Kenney is doing.

Comment: Oh, is the code in your edit executing in the body of the for loop or outside of it?

Comment: Yes Pushkin. Finally, I found that the var "len" was being used inside the loop (yep, copy-paste) so it modifies its value. Thank you all!

Comment: @JulianEzequiel Great to hear. Unless you expect the length of the array to change in the loop, I would recommend initializing `len` outside of the loop. Or just call `.length` directly in the stop condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the solution as a comment, but to "close" up the question, I'll post it here.

The problem is that the `len` variable is being changed in the body of the `for` loop, which causes it to go out of bounds.