# Newbie trying to get localStorage to work

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I can't get the  following code to say anything other than `undefined`. What am I not doing right?  I'm not sure how the score function works, either. So far I've only written vanilla `function doSomething() {}` methods.  Thank you.

```
var score = score || {};

score = {
  saveHighScore: function(tally) {
    var high_score = localStorage.high_score;
    if (typeof high_score == 'number') {
      if (tally > high_score) {
        localStorage.high_score = tally;
      }
    } else {
      localStorage.high_score = tally;
    }
  },
  getHighScore: function() {
    var high_score = localStorage.high_score;
    if(typeof high_score !== 'number') {
      high_score = 0;
      localStorage.high_score = high_score;
    }
    return high_score;
  }
}

window.console.log("Score: ", score.getHighScore());
```

Comment: `window.localStorage`?

Comment: it seems to work https://jsfiddle.net/2t6ngjvw/

Comment: The above code does not give `undefined`

Comment: I think it does give undefined, as the return value of the `console.log` but before it prints the values, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined)

Comment: I have no idea why, but I reloaded the same code posted above and it returns `Score: 0` in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is local storage stores values as string key/value pairs, so you need to parseInt:-

```js
var score = score || {};

score = {
  saveHighScore: function(tally) {
    var high_score = localStorage.high_score;
    if (typeof high_score == 'number') {
      if (tally > high_score) {
        localStorage.high_score = tally;
      }
    } else {
      localStorage.high_score = tally;
    }
  },
  getHighScore: function() {
    var high_score = parseInt(localStorage.high_score);
    if(typeof high_score !== 'number') {
      high_score = 0;
      localStorage.high_score = high_score;
    }
    return high_score;
  }
}

score.saveHighScore(100)

window.console.log("Score: ", score.getHighScore());
```

> I have no idea why, but I reloaded the same code posted above and it
>   returns Score: 0 in the console.

The reason it is returning `0`, is inside `getHighScore` it retrieves the value from local storage and compares to see if its not a number, then if it isn't you are setting it to `0`. as local storage saves all values as a string it is always setting your value to `0`.

> I'm not sure how the score function works, either

these are just functions inside an object.