# Getting unexpected behaviour with Firefox web console, equality for undefined is not working fine

Tags: javascript, mozilla

When trying to write the following JavaScript code snippet in the Firefox web console then I get the following unexpected behaviour. Please refer to the below image.

When I declared a variable x then the undefined check evaluated to true. But when I defined it as "var a" then I get a seemingly wrong answer. I have checked it for Google Chrome, and it is working fine. What is the explanation for this obscure behaviour?

[image]

Comment: You must read [ask]

Comment: You must have defined `a` variables and then cleared the console and wrote this code again... In that case, `a` is not `undefined`

Comment: Amit :Sorry ,I am new to this forum.I have read the "How to ask" webpage but I cant find any error.Can you please figure out ,at which point I made a mistake in asking?Thanks.

Comment: More generally for the Firefox web console and "undefined": *[Chrome/Firefox console.log always appends a line saying 'undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably already a global variable named `a` and it has a value. The `var a;` declaration then doesn't create a new variable. Try changing your code to:

```
if (a === undefined) {
    console.log("undefined is true");
} else {
    console.log("undefined is false, a = " + a);
}
```

so you can see the value of the variable.

Comment: Thanks I closed the browser and executed.It worked.:)

Answer (score 0):

I performed this same test in Chrome (v51.0.2704.106) and Firefox (v47.0.1), and found consistent results:

[image]