# Modifying generator function prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, generator

### TL;DR

I want to modify the prototype of a generator function instance--that is, the object returned from calling a `function*`.

---

Let's say I have a generator function:

```
function* thing(n){
    while(--n>=0) yield n;
}
```

Then, I make an instance of it:

```
let four = thing(4);
```

I want to define a prototype of generators called `exhaust`, like so:

```
four.exhaust(item => console.log(item));
```

which would produce:

```
3
2
1
0
```

I can hack it by doing this:

```
(function*(){})().constructor.prototype.exhaust = function(callback){
    let ret = this.next();
    while(!ret.done){
        callback(ret.value);
        ret = this.next();
    }
}
```

However, `(function*(){})().constructor.prototype.exhaust` seems very... hacky. There is no `GeneratorFunction` whose prototype I can readily edit... or is there? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just modify `thing.prototype`, isn't that enough? Extending builtins is quite a bad practice.

Comment: @Bergi let's say I don't have `thing` defined, and I just want to extend the prototype.

Comment: Btw, you should define `exhaust` as `for (const x of this) callback(x)` so that you get proper semantics by default

Comment: @Bergi Did this change? Cause when I run `for (var item of ['a', 'b', 'c'].where(t => true)) { console.log( item ) }` I get 4 elements, where the last is `undefined` on chrome, from the statement you made, I wouldn't expect the `undefined` value. The `where` function is in this case the generator that just returns the matching values

Comment: @Icepickle I think your problem is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined) - the `undefined` value is not from your `console.log` but rather the result of the loop. Also what is `where`, did you mean `filter`?

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, you are perfectly right :) Thanks :) Where is just a generator function for me, written like [so](https://jsfiddle.net/okvbndee/). You are perfectly right with your analysis :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> There is no `GeneratorFunction` whose prototype I can readily edit... or is there?

No, [*GeneratorFunction*  and *Generator*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-generatorfunction-objects) do not have global names indeed.

If you want to modify them… Don't. Extending builtins is an antipattern. Write a utility module of static helper functions.

> `(function*(){})().constructor.prototype` seems very... hacky. Is there a better way to do this?

I would recommend

```
const Generator = Object.getPrototypeOf(function* () {});
const GeneratorFunction = Generator.constructor;
```

then you can do

```
Generator.prototype.exhaust = function(…) { … };
```

if you really need to. But remember, if you just want to extend the generators created by `function* thing` then you can also do

```
thing.prototype.exhaust = …;
```

which is probably a better idea.

Comment: So if `GeneratorFunction` produces `Generator` objects, then is there no `Generator` function?

Comment: @Melab There is. `GeneratorFunction` produces functions that are "subclasses" of `Generator` just like `Function` produces functions that are "subclasses" of `Object` (if used as constructors). The `Generator` class is the one that actually implements the `Iterator` protocol.