# Result is getting twice by using console.log in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new in Javascript and play around with some stuff.
In Chrome console I written this code.

```
var a;
console.log(a)
```

**Output:**`undefined undefined`

Can anybody pls explane me why I am getting twice?.

[image]

Comment: because what ever variable you put in console it will automatically displayed it's value

Comment: Because `console.log()` is a function, that returns `undefined` itself.

Comment: @Itay Ya it make some sense.

Comment: `a` value is empty.so they print with `undefined`.You getting twice .i thing is the script in any loop..

Comment: Isn't it just the Chrome debugger that return a cause for the undefined?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14634066/588055

Comment: @ZackTanner Yes, I didn't get this anywhere so I posted.

Comment: @McBoman It happening in iExp as well.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log()` outputs a value to the console because you called it and that is what `console.log()` does.

The return value of the last statement is then output to the console because you are running code on the console.

It is coincidence that those values are both `undefined`.

If you set `var a = 1` then you would get `1` (what you logged) and then `undefined` (return value) instead.

Comment: `undefined` is the return value of the `console.log` function itself.

Comment: @Quentin So you mean one undefined for `consol.log()` and other which displaying `a` value in console as laty suggesting.