# Why the following code gives 'undefined' inside output

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```js
(function(){
    console.log(1);
    setTimeout (function(){console.log(2);},1000);
    setTimeout (function(){console.log(3);},0);
    console.log(4);
})();
```

Output:

```
1
4
undefined
3
2
```

Why is there an undefined in the output?

Comment: Are you testing this in Google Chrome console?

Comment: See the snippet there's no `undefined` unless you're loging something else somewhere!

Comment: I was testing in the chrome console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because return value of the function is `undefined`. So it first log 1,4,`return value of function` then it will log the values from setTimeout

For example

```
(function(){
    console.log(1);
    setTimeout (function(){console.log(2);},1000);
    setTimeout (function(){console.log(3);},0);
    console.log(4);
    return 'xyz'

})();
```

Output will be

```
1,4,'xyz',3,2
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're doing it in the console of the browser itself, then whenever you console.log it prints undefined, see this thread:

[Chrome/Firefox console.log always appends a line saying undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined)

And there's countless other threads explaining why that happens.

If this isn't in the console but in your JS file itself then there's something else somewhere else in your code that's doing it

Answer (score 4):

undefined is the return value of your function. It print undefined if you do this in browser console because it's automatically print the result of your function.

Comment: I mean the one at the top.

Comment: @LKTN.25 there is one! Its like `somevar = /*the code posted in the question*/;` so it's technically just the IIFE that counts the others are wrapped inside the IIFE itself!

Answer (score 1):

The undefined is the function return,you can try below code:

```
(function(){
        console.log(1);
        setTimeout (function(){console.log(2);},1000);
        setTimeout (function(){console.log(3);},0);
        console.log(4);
        return 5;
    })();
```