# Order of evaluation in if statement in with ES6 destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I recently stumbled upon the new [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) Javascript feature that is available with ES6.

Found out a weird situation where i am not really sure of what is going on. Hopefully you guys will help me understand.

If i type this in my console:

```
var car={}
var {undefinedProp: es6Magic} = car;
```

I get an undefined. Looks fair to me, since car has no defined property.

But if i use an If statement around it i get a different and unexpected result:

```
function testPriorities() {
      var car = {}
      if ({
          undefinedProp: es6Magic
        } = car) {
        console.log('how do i even get here', es6Magic);
      }
    }
```

**What the hell?**

Why is that es6Magic is assigned with an undefined value and it still returns true?

What rules are being applied when running the if statement?

Comment: `({undefinedProp: es6Magic} = car)` returns an empty object `Object {}`. So, it's not false..

Comment: you can't do destructuring in that way I'm afraid. Other than the fact that you're assigning rather than checking, the first part of the check is being parsed as an object, and not as syntactic sugar that is destructuring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If i type this in my console:
>
> ```
> var car={}
> var {undefinedProp: es6Magic} = car;
> ```
>
> I get an undefined.

But not because `es6Magic` has an undefined value (it does, I mean it's not the reason). It's because variable declarations have no result value, and your complete snippet does not have a result (unlike expression statements).

> But if i use an If statement around it i get a different and unexpected result:
>
> ```
> var car = {}
> if ({undefinedProp: es6Magic} = car) {
>     console.log('how do i even get here', es6Magic);
> }
> ```
>
> I guess that is true because the `car` exists, but why does it evaluate differently from the console?

Actually you'll [still get the `undefined` result from the last statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined), after the `console.log` output.

And yes, the `if` condition evaluates to a truthy value because `car` exists - that's what assignment expressions always do. This doesn't even have anything to do with destructuring, `… = car` always evaluates to the right hand side `car` regardless what the left hand side target expression is.

You can also try

```
> var car = {}, es6Magic;
undefined
> ({undefinedProp: es6Magic} = car); // no `var` - plain assignment!
[object Object]
```

Comment: That last object Object exists because Car exists?

Comment: Yes, it literally *is* the `car` object.

Answer (score 1):

The if statement executes because you are basically doing `assignment` inside `if` statement which always return the `assigned` value which in this case is `{}` which evaluates to `true`.

```js
var b

if(b={}){console.log("what!!")}

function a(){
  var car={}
  return {undefinedProp: es6Magic} = car;
}

console.log(a())
```

Comment: Does not work with undefined = undefined, so this isn't true.

Comment: basically it "ifs" the value of the thing you are making it into (and undefined is falseish)

Comment: @TiagoBértolo The assignment returns the value which is being assigned(on the right side of `=`) which in your question is `{}` and `{}` evalutes to `true`

Comment: @anuragasaurus But what rule are you applying to say that?

Comment: es6Magic is assigned with an undefined value and it still returns true.

Answer (score 1):

The console shows `undefined` because a variable declaration doesn't return anything, it declares a variable.

The second version works because `{foo: bar}` is interpreted as an object literal, which you are assigning to. That returns the object, which is truthy. I would expect that to throw an error, which it does in the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target

The literal shouldn't be a valid target, but a transpiler would most likely break that.

Comment: Everything is perfectly valid in my code sample. Not sure what you are refering to. Can you clarify?