# Chrome console not running commands?

Tags: google-chrome

Any reason my chrome console is behaving like this. It won't run even the simplest of commands.

[image: screenshot of console]

Why will not even emit simple variables like this:[image]

```
var car = "blue";
console.log(car);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined

Comment: Hmm not sure I was gonna say to check your logging level but it looks like you have it set to Verbose. If you `console.log(window)`, what happens? Also what chrome version?

Comment: I get the window object plus undefined. Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Is it just `console.log` or everything else too? Does it happen on every web page or only on something specific? Does it happen also in Incognito mode with plugins disabled?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome/Firefox console.log always appends a line saying undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined)