# How to understand provided forEach behavior with class instance in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I can't really understand the console.log last output.

**It prints:**

```
constructor  -  ƒ Array() { [native code] }
speak  -  undefined
undefined
```

1) Why is speak - undefined?
2) Why there is the third output line - just - undefined? Where does it get from?

```js
class Bar { 
    speak() { 
        let text = 'test';
        alert(text);
        return text;
    } 
}
var test = new Bar;

z = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(test));
console.log(typeof z, " - ", z);

console.log(z.forEach(function(e) { console.log(e, " - ", z[e]); }));
```

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: `z.forEach(function(e) { console.log(e, " - ", z[e]); })` doesn't return any value, so you get `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking `z[e]` instead of `test[e]`. `z` is an array of property names, and arrays do not have a `speak` property, unlike `Bar` objects, which do have a `speak` property.

That explains the `speak - undefined` line. The final standalone `undefined` is the return value of `console.log` itself: [Chrome/Firefox console.log always appends a line saying undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined)