# Mozilla Firebug console.log() displays the answer as undefined

Tags: javascript, firebug

I am using Firebug for the first time and when I type

```
var a = 10;
console.log("value of a: " + a);
```

the response I get on the console is "undefined".

I suppose the syntax was correct, and I tried using it with `alert` and `document`. It worked fine, but Firebug isn't showing any output. How can I fix this?

[image: Console screenshot]

Note: I am talking about Firebug, the extension for Mozilla Firefox, not Firefox's built-in developer tools.

Comment: The console log is returning the value just fine 'value of a: 10'

Comment: Is it showing only undefined? "undefined" could be the return value of console.log (which is as expected). Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Mine is returning the value as "undefined". what could be the reason?

Comment: @Vasan I have put up a screenshot. plz check.

Comment: Please note that [Firebug is discontinued](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/10/saying-goodbye-to-firebug/) and stops working with Firefox 57. Therefore Firefox users are advised to use the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) instead.

Comment: @SebastianZartner: Wow, Firefox's devtools look so similar to FireBug that I assumed the OP was using devtools, not actually using FireBug...

Comment: They look similar when the Firebug theme is turned on, yes. That's intended to make the transition for Firebug users easier. Downside is that many people don't realize that they are actually using a different tool, because there is no obvious hint, and then wonder why "Firebug" behaves differently.

Comment: Strongly recommend not continuing to use a discontinued extension, esp. as the built-in devtools are at least as good and don't have this issue (whatever it is).

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me out!

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[Chrome/Firefox console.log always appends a line saying 'undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968)*

Answer (score 2):

Separate expressions. Based on the screenshot, firefox displays the result of the first expression