# For...of : undefined log

Tags: javascript, arrays, cycle, console.log

I got this simple function, and I want to console out the values in an array:

```
function findRoutes(routes) {
    for (let value of routes) {
        console.log(value)
    } }


console.log(findRoutes([["MNL", "TAG"], ["CEB", "TAC"], ["TAG", "CEB"], ["TAC", "BOR"]]))
```

my console is:

```
["MNL", "TAG"]
["CEB", "TAC"]
["TAG", "CEB"]
["TAC", "BOR"]
undefined
```

What's that "undefined" at the end?

Comment: You’re `console.log`ging the return value of `findRoutes`, but it doesn’t return anything.

Comment: Ah... damn... you're pretty right!.

Comment: @Ry︁ is right. I would expect `findRoutes` to return a value based on its name. Currently it is confusing.

Comment: What name you wants to use to filter array?

Comment: @MohammadUsman dont want to filter... it was the function return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Javascript**,

> We know the **functions** returned value could be an `object`, an `array`, a
>   `function`, a `boolean`, `string` and so on. But If the function has
>   no `return` statement, `undefined` is returned. When you run any
>   **void** function (like console.log) from the console, it also prints out info about the return value, **undefined** in this case.

Read the top 2 voted answers here [Chrome/Firefox console.log always appends a line saying undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined) to clearly understand why you see the last `undefined` after your array?. I had same confusion few month back about the last **undefined**.

Comment: I see... sometimes is confusing.