# Prompt for age delivers unexpected result

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I'm currently starting to learn JavaScript. However, can someone tell me what's wrong with the program below and how come only age 18 is being accepted? When age is <18 or >18, I am getting undefined result at the chrome console when I run this code from the console:

```js
var age = prompt("What is your age?");
if (Number(age) < 18) {
  alert("Sorry, you are too young to drive this car. Powering off");
} else if (Number(age) > 18) {
  alert("Powering On. Enjoy the ride!");
} else if (Number(age) === 18) {
  alert("Congratulations on your first year of driving. Enjoy the ride!");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when age is <18 or >18, i am getting undefined result at the chrome console"? Is it not printing the error messages? And you're using alert, not console.log. It won't put results in the console. It will popup an alert.

Comment: Where did you get undefined? I got it nowhere

Comment: it is working fine :) what is not working for you?

Comment: The code works perfectly. Not sure what you mean

Comment: Don't worry about that....is just a `console` response...for example if you open the console and type `var test = 13` and press enter, it prints `undefined`...you can take a look at this Q&A for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome/Firefox console.log always appends a line saying undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of your quick replies. When i answer 18 to  the prompt question "What is your age", there will be an alert of Congratulations on your first year of driving. Enjoy the ride!". However, when I answer <  18 and >  18, I am not getting any alert result but undefined in the chrome console...Thanks.

Comment: I am expecting the alert statements  if I answer < 18 or > 18 in the prompt command.

Comment: The code as pasted works as expected

Comment: Ok. thanks everyone.. Maybe its just a problem on the console.

Comment: Feel free to delete the question since it is not useful to anyone but you.

Answer (score 0):

The console environment in your browser is designed to take the very last statement expression in a program and evaluate it for a value and then show you that value. You get undefined if the statement does not return anything.

For example, if you type `var x = 2` in your console, you will get undefined, but if you type `x = 2`, you will get 2.

Answer (score -1):

If it's already a number you don't typically need to use Number() to convert it to a number.

And, if it's an normal integer there is no reason to believe that Number() should convert it to anything but the number.

The only possible issue is I can imagine is that "age" isn't the expected value when you run your code snippet.

Comment: The code works and the question will be closed as "Not reproducible" - the problem is console always returning undefined when pasting stuff in