# "const" variable not defined when used with "console.log"

Tags: javascript, scope, constants

I'm currently playing around with "const" variable in javascript and here is my code

[image]

My question is, why is "const x" undefined when used with "console.log", but it is defined when used on its own?

p.s. -- I understand that both global "const, let" do not become the property of "window" object, unlike global "var". But I am unsure as to whether this played any role in the code above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome/Firefox console.log always appends a line saying undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing `undefined` because `console.log()` function actually returns you that.

Notice how `x` is still `123` when you query just `x`?

The assignment operation for `const x = 123;` is undefined because it returns you `undef` as well.

Comment: can you please explain to me why "console.log(x);" does not print out the value of "const x"?

Comment: The value should be printed in the `console`, not in your debug window. The latter is meant for you to `debug` what value gets returned from a particular operation not what is printed.

Answer (score 2):

What browser/version are you using? Trying it in both FF65 and Chromium71, `console.log( x );` indeed gives me 123 ...