# Unexpected result when checking undefined value

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with a length of at most 4 and at least 1. Here, I check which elements exist and do things accordingly.

```
function sendToGroup(receiver_group) {
  if (receiver_group[0] !== undefined){
    console.log(receiver_group[0])
  }

  if(receiver_group[1] !== undefined){
    console.log(receiver_group[1])
  }

  if(receiver_group[2] !== undefined){
    console.log(receiver_group[2])
  }

  if(receiver_group[3] !== undefined){
    console.log(receiver_group[3])
  }
}
```

When I give the array of 2 elements to this function, I see first and second element as expected in the console output but I also see an undefined in the line of

```
console.log(receiver_group[2])
```

How is this even possible? If it is undefined(which it is) this logging code should not get executed.

Edit: Chrome says the length of the array is 2. Which It is. 
receiver_group is an array. which has the content of

```
[{id:12, name:"name", age:"21"}, {id:22, name:"name", age:25}]
```

Also same thing doesn't happen for the item 4 which has the index of 3.

Comment: Can you show how this code is executed?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a `console.log` after printing `undefined`? How do you know it's from `console.log(receiver_group[2])`?

Comment: You'll have to post more of your code.

Comment: The best way to get help, is to provide a [mcve].

Comment: chrome shows the logging is coming from which line. That is how I know the code gets executed. Also following functions are works too.

Comment: Also, why not simply `receiver_group.forEach(x => console.log(x));`?

Comment: @JohnColeman I know that is the way to do it. But that is not the problem here.

Comment: @AkilDemir what is receiver_group?

Comment: @AniketG It is an array.

Comment: @AkilDemir I meant what's the value of it. Please put that into your post

Comment: Perhaps it is the *string* `"undefined"`? On the one hand `undefined !== undefined` is always false, but on the other hand, `"undefined" !== undefined` is true. What does `console.log(receiver_group.length);` return in this case?

Comment: @AniketG Okay. I will change the post.

Comment: Try running `undefined == undefined` in the JavaScript console and see if the answer is what you expected. My guess is that you're looking for the `typeof` function.

Comment: @mzedeler but `undefined == undefined` is `true`

Comment: @JohnColeman it is 2.

Comment: When I take your current code and add to it the line `sendToGroup([{id:12, name:"name", age:"21"}, {id:22, name:"name", age:25}]);` in a .js file and run it in node, I see nothing unexpected printed . Are you sure that you are not running that line in the console? Please give a [mcve] -- with an emphasis on *verifiable*.
`

Answer (score 4):

It is also printing **undefined**, if I execute the below code:

```
if(1==2){}
```

> In the console you can type a name of a variable (for example try
>   typing window) and it prints info about it. When you run any void
>   function (like console.log) from the console, it also prints out info
>   about the return value, undefined in this case.

So, the undefined printed after logging [0] and [1] value is the correct behavior as it is trying to print the return value which is undefined.

Please refer to the answer: [Chrome/Firefox console.log always appends a line saying undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined)

Comment: My point was It should not even enter the  inside of if statement. Because What I am saying is log the output if it is not undefined in the code.

Comment: @AkilDemir The point of this answer is that perhaps it isn't entering that statement at all -- the `undefined` could be triggered by the *second* log -- if you are running this code directly in the console rather than from a .js file. As an experiment, replace `console.log(receiver_group[2])` by `console.log("test")`. Is `"test"` printed?

Comment: I am running the code from .js file and not only logging, the code under the console.log is also running. I mean tries to run but since receiver_group[2] is undefined It can't and gives error.