# Answer following Interesting Interview Questions

Tags: javascript

## What is the Output of the following lines:

Kindly post your respective answers so that we all can get some clarity in depth.

console.log(1 +- "2" + "2"); 
console.log(1 +- "1" + "2"); 
console.log(+"1" + "1" + "2"); 
console.log("A"-"B"+"2"); 
console.log("A"-"B"+2);

#### Note:

*The main purpose of asking this question here is:*

***Why 2 values (Undefined & some value) are printing when checking in console?***

Can any one please solve my doubt?
Thanks inadvance.

Comment: Maybe this question would get closed.

Comment: @krishna maybe. Not sure how that comment is helpful.

Comment: I don't see a question? What is your question?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. kindly Provide your answers for those above lines.

Comment: @JonasWilms For a true knowledge seeker, that comment would have triggered the inquisitiveness to ask why

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome/Firefox console.log always appends a line saying undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined)

Answer (score -1):

Every Statement returns undefined.

```
console.log(1 + "-2" + "2");  // undefined
console.log(1 +- "1" + "2"); // undefined 
console.log(+"1" + "1" + "2"); // undefined 
console.log("A"-"B"+"2"); // undefined 
console.log("A"-"B"+2); // undefined
```

Comment: They **do** return `undefined`, but they also print something to the console. I believe the OP wanted to find out why those outputs were the way they were.