# DOMContentLoaded event in JavaScript is not triggering

Tags: javascript, firefox, tampermonkey, userscripts

Here is my very simple code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   console.log('Your document is ready!');
});
```

I paste it in the developer console of the browser. However, it does not log anything. Could anyone please help me find out why is it happening?

All I get after executing the script is `undefined`. The same code works if I remove the loading wrapper.

```
console.log('Your document is ready!');
```

I want to run the script in Tampermonkey. Here is the original script:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  document.querySelector("._3xiuDJ ._52MoHd").innerHTML = 'Test';
});
```

With the DOM load event, it does not do anything. Without the DOM load event, I get the following error:

```
document.querySelector(...) is null
```

If I directly paste it in the developer console like this,

```
document.querySelector("._3xiuDJ ._52MoHd").innerHTML = 'Test';
```

It works perfectly.

If I place it in the Tampermonkey script. It gives me the above null error. If I place it inside the wrapper in the Tampermonkey script, it does not do anything.

Thanks.

Comment: The event fires _when_ the DOM has loaded. The DOM, presumably, has already loaded when you open the console and run the code so it won't fire the event (again). The `undefined` [is expected behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14634066/1377002).

Comment: Thanks @Andy. :)

I run the same code using the Tapermonkey Addon (https://www.tampermonkey.net/) and it still does not work.

Comment: I need to access some DOM elements. So, if I run the code with DOM load event, I still get an error.

Comment: You should just be able to access the DOM without checking to see if its loaded (I've written a number of addons and have never had to perform that check). Perhaps if you update your question with the code you're using to try and access the DOM, and a sample of the HTML as a [mcve] we could check to see why that code doesn't work intead.

Comment: @Andy I have added the code with the changes.

Comment: In your script header have you got a @run-at command? If you have, remove it. The only other thing I can think of is that the portion of HTML you're trying to access is being dynamically loaded _after_ the DOM has loaded, and that's why you can't immediately grab it.

Comment: Thanks @Andy. You were right, the content was loading dynamically. I did some tests to verify this and finally ended up using a timer to check if the element has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In your script header have you got a @run-at command? If you have, remove it.

The only other thing I can think of is that the portion of HTML you're trying to access is being dynamically loaded after the DOM has loaded, and that's why you can't immediately grab it.

– Andy Aug 11 at 11:57