# Passing an element to function, creating id variable, using this variable to smooth scroll to element

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I am trying to work out why the following is happening.

I am trying to:

- Click an element.
- On click, pass a DOM element to a function.
- Use this DOM element within the function to create a target ID.
- Smooth Scroll to this target ID>

Here is my code:

VARIABLE:

```
var productListQueryResult  = $('#product-list-query-result');
```

TRIGGER:

```
scrollToDiv(productListQueryResult);
```

FUNCTION:

```
// TO TOP OF ELEMENT
function scrollToDiv(e) {
    var el = e.attr('id');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + el).offset().top
    }, 300);
    console.log(el);
}
// END TO TOP OF ELEMENT
```

RESULT:

```
jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#product-list-query-result'
```

Although this element is in existence. If I run:

```
var e = jQuery("#product-list-query-result");
console.log(e);
```

I get two lines returned:

```
a.fn.init [div#product-list-query-result, context: document, selector: "#product-list-query-result"]
undefined
```

I'm unsure as to why I get a second line returned too 'undefined', can anyone explain that too?

Hopefully I have provided enough information, if not please feel free to start a discussion.

### Edit

I have also tried:

TRIGGER:

```
scrollToDiv(productListQueryResult.attr('id'));
```

FUNCTION:

```
// TO TOP OF ELEMENT
function scrollToDiv(e) {
    var el = "'#" + e + "'";
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(el).offset().top
    }, 300);
    console.log(el);
}
// END TO TOP OF ELEMENT
```

RESULT:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#product-list-query-result'
```

**EDIT** (SOLUTION):

If passing a variable into the selector you do not require the ""'s.

FUNCTION:

```
// TO TOP OF ELEMENT
function scrollToDiv(e) {
    var el = "#" + e;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(el).offset().top
    }, 300);
    console.log(el);
}
// END TO TOP OF ELEMENT
```

I am still confused why the first attempt wouldn't have worked, and why the simple test returned an undefined line?

Comment: The error you get `unrecognized expression: '#product-list-query-result'` is weird... Could it be that you are using another library that overwrites the `$` variable and when you call `$('#product-list-query-result');` that `$` it's actually not jQuery?

Comment: I am using WordPress' already hosted version, then assigning $ within the ready function: (function($){})(jQuery);

Comment: Mmmm, it's strange then. Your code seems to work. You can take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hLcbngy9/) where it is working.

Comment: That fiddle doesn't load any JS. I believe you though, that's why I wrote it like that xD If you have any revelations on the topic, please do feedback!

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to save it :face_palm. In the answer I wrote I updated it and it's working, though :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit complicated for what you want to achieve. You are storing a jQuery element into `productListQueryResult` but then you are retrieving its `id` in order to get it again by id.

A simpler solution would be:

```
// We already have the element.
var productListQueryResult  = $('#product-list-query-result');

scrollToDiv(productListQueryResult);

// TO TOP OF ELEMENT
function scrollToDiv(el) {
    // We don't need to get the element again, as we already have it.
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: el.offset().top
    }, 300);
    console.log(el);
}
```

As to why your code did not work, your first try worked for me, as you can see in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/08hns73o/).

In your second try you were computing the id incorrectly:

```
var el = "'#" + e + "'";
```

In this way, `el` ended up with value `"'#product-list-query-result'"` (note the single quotes) and that is not a valid selector for jQuery, hence the `unrecognized expression` error.

As to why the `undefined` line in your `console.log`, it doesn't mean that your HTML element was not present. With:

```
var e = jQuery("#product-list-query-result");
console.log(e);
```

You got in console:

```
a.fn.init [div#product-list-query-result, context: document, selector: "#product-list-query-result"]
undefined
```

The first line is the result of your `console.log(e)`.

The why of the second line is better explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined). In few words, is the return of `console.log` command that also gets printed.

Comment: I previously tried your simple solution but it just returned Uncaught TypeError: e.offset is not a function. Appreciate the intel on the additional console.log!