# JavaScript function returning undefined + console log

Tags: javascript

[image]

Can someone help me fix my thousandTrees() function, it displaying the console log that i want, but it is also returning undefined on the console.

How do i make the function just do the console log?

this is part of an exercise from a course i am following.

The function is just at the bottom of the code

thank you

```
// park constructor
class Park {
    constructor (name, buildYear, trees, size) {
        this.name = name;
        this.buildYear = buildYear;
        this.trees = trees;
        this.size = size;
    }

    // number of tree / park area
    treeDensity() {
        return this.trees / this.size;
    }

    // return the park age
    parkAge() {
        return new Date().getFullYear() - this.buildYear;
    }
}

// street constructor
class Street {
    constructor (name, buildYear, size) {
        this.name = name;
        this.buildYear = buildYear;
        this.size = size;
    }
};


// all parks

let allParks = [
    park1 = new Park("Brighton Park", 1900, 1200, 3),
    park2 = new Park("Worthing Park", 1800, 650, 2),
    park3 = new Park("Shoreham Park", 1850, 350, 2)
]
// all streets

let allStreets = [
    street1 = new Street("Brighton Street", 1858, 2000),
    street2 = new Street("Worthing Street", 1950, 1200),
    street3 = new Street("Shoreham Street", 1850, 800),
    street4 = new Street("Lancing Street", 1980, 760)
];

// calculate the average age of all parks
let parkAgeAvg = function() {
    return (park1.parkAge() + park2.parkAge() + park3.parkAge()) / 3
};
// Display the name of the park with more than 1000 trees
let thousandTrees = function() {
    for (let cur of allParks) {
        if (cur.trees >= 1000) {
          console.log(`${cur.name} has more than 1000 trees, we have verified there is actually ${cur.trees} trees in total.`);
        }
    }
};

// total length of streets and avg length

//size classification of all streets
```

Comment: What do you want it to return? Also, your indentation is very deceiving.

Comment: Are you sure it's the code you posted that's logging the `undefined`? Anything else present on the page?

Comment: I think the problem is in instance creation. You store it in array but your code does not initialize it.

Comment: I dont really want to return anything, just want a function that when called, looks within the array for any property of trees that has 1000 or more and console log it.

I am getting really confused at the moment as i am trying to rush through the course and i know there is some very basic error i am doing here, just dont know what!

Comment: salman ahmed, i am just calling it in the console for the moment for testing only

Comment: for (let cur of allParks) { after this line console.log(cur)

Comment: I don't see where you defined variables park1, park2 and park3 , but you have these names in array ?

Comment: That is not an error. Without going into too much detail about the inner workings, that is how Chrome console works. The extra 'undefined' line is expected.

Comment: Thank you tlong314 i will ignore it for now then :p

Comment: No problem. Here is another reference with some more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `undefined` you're seeing is just because the function you're calling in the console *returns* `undefined`, and any JS you evaluate in the console shows the value of the expression. It has nothing to do with the console logging code.

Side note, there's a problem in how you're initializing things:

```
let allParks = [
    park1 = new Park("Brighton Park", 1900, 1200, 3),
    park2 = new Park("Worthing Park", 1800, 650, 2),
    park3 = new Park("Shoreham Park", 1850, 350, 2)
]
```

In some modes, JavaScript would choke on this, because `park1`, `park2`, and `park3` are undefined. I believe what you actually want is just:

```
let allParks = [
    new Park("Brighton Park", 1900, 1200, 3),
    new Park("Worthing Park", 1800, 650, 2),
    new Park("Shoreham Park", 1850, 350, 2)
]
```

In the former, you're populating the array with the results of *assignment expressions*. In the second, you're populating it with constructed objects.

Same feedback for `allStreets`.

Comment: Try putting "use strict"; on top of script and you will see errors of undefined variables. It is bad practice to use values in array like that.

Comment: Thank you guys, you are correct about this.

In the first place i didnt have them inside an array , but thoough i would then put them inside an array so i could iterate over them

Will fix the issue, but haven't seen any bugs yet? how come?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In chrome I'm not seeing any errors in the console.log

```js
// park constructor
class Park {
    constructor (name, buildYear, trees, size) {
        this.name = name;
        this.buildYear = buildYear;
        this.trees = trees;
        this.size = size;
    }

    // number of tree / park area
    treeDensity() {
        return this.trees / this.size;
    }

    // return the park age
    parkAge() {
        return new Date().getFullYear() - this.buildYear;
    }
}

// street constructor
class Street {
    constructor (name, buildYear, size) {
        this.name = name;
        this.buildYear = buildYear;
        this.size = size;
    }
};


// all parks

let allParks = [
    park1 = new Park("Brighton Park", 1900, 1200, 3),
    park2 = new Park("Worthing Park", 1800, 650, 2),
    park3 = new Park("Shoreham Park", 1850, 350, 2)
]
// all streets

let allStreets = [
    street1 = new Street("Brighton Street", 1858, 2000),
    street2 = new Street("Worthing Street", 1950, 1200),
    street3 = new Street("Shoreham Street", 1850, 800),
    street4 = new Street("Lancing Street", 1980, 760)
];

// calculate the average age of all parks
let parkAgeAvg = function() {
    return (park1.parkAge() + park2.parkAge() + park3.parkAge()) / 3
};
// Display the name of the park with more than 1000 trees
let thousandTrees = function() {
    for (let cur of allParks) {
        if (cur.trees >= 300) {
          console.log(`${cur.name} has more than 1000 trees, we have verified there is actually ${cur.trees} trees in total.`);
        }
    }
};

thousandTrees();
```

Answer (score 0):

Define variables which ones you use in arrays:

```
// all parks
let park1,park2,park3;

let allParks = [
     park1 = new Park("Brighton Park", 1900, 1200, 3),
     park2 = new Park("Worthing Park", 1800, 650, 2),
     park3 = new Park("Shoreham Park", 1850, 350, 2)
]
// all streets
let street1, street2, street3, street4;

let allStreets = [
    street1 = new Street("Brighton Street", 1858, 2000),
    street2 = new Street("Worthing Street", 1950, 1200),
    street3 = new Street("Shoreham Street", 1850, 800),
    street4 = new Street("Lancing Street", 1980, 760)
];
```