# Why is "console.log" being executed every time the function is called, but "return" is executed only once?

Tags: javascript, output, execution

```js
function foo() {
  console.log('always');
  return 'once'
}

foo()
foo()
foo()
```

The output looks like - 
always
always
always
once

I want to know what happens during execution so that "always" is printed thrice but "once" is printed (returned) only once.

Comment: Your function is returning a string and you're not doing anything with it.

Comment: Just do `foo(); 'repl result'` instead to understand what's going on.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined

Answer (score 4):

The reason is JS console always evaluates the last expression and prints its output to the console. In reality, your `foo()` function is returning a value in all 3 calls. It is your last call of `foo()` that gets printed to the console. To see this yourself, append another expression to the end of your code:

```js
function foo(){
  console.log('always');
  return 'once'
}

foo()
foo()
foo()
a = 42
```

This time your output would be

```
always
always
always
42
```