# Where is "undefined" coming from here?

Tags: javascript, function

I have the following code:

```
console.log(doSomething);
doSomething();

function doSomething() {
    console.log("Declare something");
}
```

which in the console returns

```
[Function: doSomething]
Declare something
```

But when I write

```
console.log(doSomething());

function doSomething() {
    console.log("Declare something");
}
```

the console says

```
Declare something
undefined
```

I understand why it just says "Declare something" and not "[Function: doSomething]", but why does it say "undefined"? Why does it not say "Declare something Declare something"?

Comment: The default return value of a function is `undefined` which is what you see there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome/Firefox console.log always appends a line saying undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undefined is the return value of the function.
Change your function for this for example to prove it.

```
function doSomething() {
    console.log("Declare something");
    return "test";
}
```

Comment: I added `return "Declare something";` and now the console says `Declare something Declare something` as expected. I had assumed that a `console.log` output counted as a return value but now I understand that it does not. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The second log is regarding your `console.log(doSomething());` which is printing the `return` of your function. In this case, you are not returning anything and therefore it prints `undefined`.

Comment: Ah, I added `return "Declare something";` and now the console says `Declare something Declare something`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you didn't declare the return statement of the function.