# Generator function in javascript functionality

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

i am totally new to javascript in ES6 i know very basic about javascript

```
function *GeneratorFunction(i) { 
while (i < 4) { 
i += yield i; 
} 
return i;
}
var gen = GeneratorFunction(3);
console.log(gen.next(1));
console.log(gen.next(1));
console.log(gen.next(1));
```

output is below

```
{value: 3, done: false}// this is when statement is get true
{value: 4, done: true}// ? didn't get this point
{value: undefined, done: true}// ?
undefined //?
```

i dont know why output is in keyvalue pair.
please answer "?" in outputs.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

Comment: For your second question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined

Answer (score 1):

This is how [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) works. First you have to invoke the generator function i.e `GeneratorFunction` which will give you `iterator` object.

```
var gen = GeneratorFunction(3);
```

When you invoke the `next` function of gen(returned iterator object) will returns an object which can contains 2 properties i.e `value` or `done`

The `value` property contains the value of the iteration and `done` tells us whether there is more value we can get from `gen` or not.

**Example** In the below snippet, when you invoke `next` method of `iterator` then it produces an object in which your value is in `value` property and `done` shows whether you can get more value from `generator function` or not.

After the `done` is `true`, All value will be `undefined` doesn't matter how many times you invoke the `next`method

```js
function* GeneratorFunction(i) {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}
var gen = GeneratorFunction(1);

console.log(gen.next());
console.log(gen.next());
console.log(gen.next());
console.log(gen.next());
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**NOTE:**  Most of the time you use `generator function` with `for..of` loop which will give you the value directly as

```js
function* GeneratorFunction(i) {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}
var gen = GeneratorFunction(1);

for (let val of gen) {
  console.log(val);
}
```

---

**UPDATED: FUNCTION INVOCATION**

When you invoke the generator function

```
var gen = GeneratorFunction(3);
```

It passes the value of `i` as `3` and the invocation of the Generator function starts until the first `yield` and generator function suspend and produces value as:

```
{ value: 3, done: false }
```

Since, the `done` is `false` so the generator function take charge and starts again with input value as `1` that will replace the `yield` and it is same as:

```
i += yield i;  // same as i += 1;
```

and the value of `i` is now `4` which doesn't satisfy the condition of `while` loop and exits from the loop.

After that

```
return i;
```

which returns the object as

```
{ value: 4, done: true }
```

> If a generator function returns a value, then the final call to `next`
> returns an object that has both `value` and `done` defined. The value
> property holds the return value of the generator function, and the
> `done` property is `true`, indicating that there are no more value to
> iterate.

After the `done` is `true` then the further invocation will return `value` as `undefined` and `done` as `true`.

*I've changed snippet to simplify the returned value from the generator function as*

```js
function* GeneratorFunction(i) {
  while (i < 4) {
    i += yield i;
  }
  return "final value";
}
var gen = GeneratorFunction(3);
console.log(gen.next(1));
console.log(gen.next(1));
console.log(gen.next(1));
console.log(gen.next(1));
console.log(gen.next(1));
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: than why does my output is like this

{value: 3, done: false}//if generator function have done false than why it becomes true in next line of output? and in 3rd line of output it is again true and value is undefine
{value: 4, done: true}
{value: undefined, done: true}

Comment: Updated answer. Hope you will get what you were expecting... 

Comment: Lovely explanation thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use console.log(gen.next().value) instead of console.log(gen.next(1)) for the output you want, which will prevent to get the output in key value pair.