# console.log statement differs when I execute it inside the function and outside the function

Tags: javascript, function, console, output, hoisting

```
function func(){
  var name
  console.log(name)
  name="pavan"
  console.log(name)
}

func()
```

When I run the above code
it gives me the output `undefined pavan`.

---

```
var name
console.log(name)
name="pavan"
console.log(name)
```

When I run this modified code it's logging `pavan pavan`.

What's the difference?

Comment: Typing commands into the console can produce confusing "<- undefined" output.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined  Your function `func`, while being a totally valid function, doesnt return anything, so your console logs "undefined" when you call it.

Comment: No when i run it in html it gives undefined and pavan but when I try the other one its giving me pavan and pavan

Comment: because global is `window.name`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are reusing same variable names when running your experiments.

Consider:

```js
var name;
name = 'pavan'
var name;
console.log(name); // prints pavan
```

If you use different variable names in both snippets, you will get expected output:

```
var name1;
console.log(name1);  // prints undefined
name1="pavan";
console.log(name1);  // prints pavan
```

Also note that `name` is a property of `Window` object.
See [Window: name property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name)