# What does the arrow mean in developer console? Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, google-developers-console

After every operation in developer console "<- undefined" appears, What does it mean? Arrow and gray undefined?
I already made log "12", what is it additional "<- undefined"?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It appears to be the returned result of the expression that was evaluated.  So for example `console.log(12)` logs `12` to the console and then *returns* `undefined`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined could help?

Answer (score 3):

that's the return value of the thing you typed. for example, console.log() prints something to the console and then returns undefined.