# Return statement not printing to console?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return, console.log

When I run the following code, it only prints to the console "Checkpoint X" but not the return statement:

```
function match(player, computer){
    
    console.log(`Player choice is ${player} and computer choice is ${computer}`);

    if (player === computer){
        console.log("Checkpoint 1")
       return "It's a draw!";
    } else if (player == 'Rock' && computer == 'Paper'){
        console.log("Checkpoint 2")
        return "Computer wins";
    } else if (player == 'Rock' && computer == 'Scissors'){
        console.log("Checkpoint 3")
        return "Player wins";
    } else if (player == 'Paper' && computer == 'Rock'){
        console.log("Checkpoint 4")
        return "Player wins";
    } else if (player == 'Paper' && computer == 'Scissors'){
        console.log("Checkpoint 5")
        return "Computer wins";
    } else if (player == 'Scissors' && computer == 'Rock'){
        console.log("Checkpoint 6")
        return "Computer wins";
    } else if (player == 'Scissors' && computer == 'Paper'){
        console.log("Checkpoint 7")
        return "Player wins";
    } else {
        return "Match error!";
    }
}
```

However, when I enter in the console directly `match(player,computer);` it prints to the console both "Checkpoint X" and the associated return statement.

Does anyone know why this is?

FOR ADDITIONAL CONTEXT:
This is what I see when I go to console!

[image]

Comment: That's how the console works. You type in an expression statement, and it prints the result of executing the expression.

Comment: @Pointy that has not answered my question. My question is why when the code runs does it only print the console log statement but when I manually enter the function into the console log it prints both the console log statement AND the return statement?

Comment: Are you asking why a `return` statement does not print its value to the console? The answer is that it is not supposed to; `return` doesn't have anything to do with the console.

Comment: No I repeated my question and unfortunately you still do not understand. When I enter `match(player,computer);` into the console log it does print both the console log statement and the return statement. Why does it do that but not print the return statement when I actually run the code?

Comment: Let's say you call the function like this: `const result = match(1, 1);`. That will not cause the returned value to print to the console; why do you think it would? Now, if your code then has `console.log(result)`, you **will** see the returned value, because you're passing it to `console.log()`.

Comment: @Pointy you unfortunately continue to misunderstand my query after lots of repetition in different ways! Of course your example would not print to console because you've made result a variable so it will not. I'm using the return statement so I'm not sure what the relevance is?!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking why this happens in the console or why this doesn't happen outside the console? The `return` statement itself doesn't print anything. Only in the console, you can see the result of your statement as a debugging help.

Comment: @Jabaa pls see the picture I've added to see if that makes it clearer

Comment: No, it doesn't make it clearer. What is your question? Are you asking why you see the results in the console or are you asking why this doesn't happen outside the console? Can you formulate a clear and specific question? _"Does anyone know why this is?"_ Yes, most JavaScript developers on Stack Overflow know why this is.

Comment: @Jabaa if you take a look at the picture you will see that when my code runs it ONLY prints the console log statement but when I run the function from console, it prints the console log statement AND it prints the return statement. Do you know why that is? Is it happenstance? Is it coincidence?

Comment: why does my code respond differently when it is run vs when I run the function in the console?

Comment: I repeat: _"The return statement itself doesn't print anything. Only in the console, you can see the result of your statement as a debugging help."_ It's a helpful browser feature to support the developer. This behavior is not part of the JavaScript language.

Comment: @Jabaa thank you for understanding and providing helpful insight.

Comment: Note that my very first comment said exactly the same thing.

Comment: It's the same as [Chrome/Firefox console.log always appends a line saying 'undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined)

Comment: @Pointy your very first comment does not say the exact same thing. You gave me an example where you turned return into a variable.

Comment: But Pointy is right. The first comment describes it. I've only repeated the first comment and added that it's helpful for developers. That's the reason your question was unclear. It was answered in the first comment, but you kept asking.

Comment: When you run a function it stores the return statement as the response of the function but we are not printing it. When you run code in the console, it is considered as console.log(match(1,1))

Answer (score 1):

When you run a function it stores the return statement as the response of the function but we are not printing it. When you run code in the console, it is considered as
`console.log(match(1,1))`

Comment: It's not only functions. It's all expression statements.

Comment: yes I was answering in terms of questions implementation

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example function:

```
function example(a, b) {
    console.log(`Inside example: a is ${a}, b is ${b}`);
    return a + b;
}
```

When that function is called, no matter how, or with what parameters, you'll see a message show up in the browser console (or the Node console if you're running it there). That's clearly because there's a `console.log()` call sitting right there at the top of the function.

So if you call it from someplace (in your code, not the console):

```
example(2, 3);
```

you'll see the message. The function will then add the two parameters together and return that result. In this case, the function is called but the return value is ignored. The return value is therefore basically thrown away by the runtime. The value is not logged to the console or saved anywhere else; it's simply gone.

The function could also be called as part of an expression:

```
someObject.sum = example(2, 3) + 5; // 10
```

Now the return value is used in the expression in the *calling* environment. The function is called, the message is logged, the sum is returned. That sum will then be added to 5, and that overall result is stored in `someObject.sum`.  This time the returned value *is* used, not thrown away. Nevertheless, the value will not itself be implicitly logged to the console.

Of course, in the same way, the returned value from the function call *can* be logged to the console:

```
console.log(example(2, 3));
```

Or it can be used as part of an expression that's sent to the log:

```
console.log(`summing 2 and 3: ${example(2, 3)}`);
```

Overall the point I'm making is that a function call that involves a `return` statement will never *automatically* produce output in the console.

Now, that said, when we go *to the console input* and type in a call to example:

```
> example(2, 3)
```

there will indeed be two messages logged. The first is the message from the function. The second message logged will be the value returned by the function. It's not logged because it came from a `return` statement or the function call itself, but rather because that's the value of the *expression* `example(2, 3)`. If we instead type into the console

```
> example(2, 3) + 5
```

the second message will be 10, not 5, because the value of that expression includes the function return value *and* the addition operation, all of which produces one numeric result. The console always produces a result value from a snippet of code you type in, even though there might be no value. That's why if you go to the console and type

```
> let x = 0;
```

you'll see a message that says `undefined`, because a `let` statement has no result value.

Answer (score -1):

You need to explicitly return the `console.log` statement

You can also `return` the same statement and it will be returned from the function where you can use it in other parts of your code.

```js
...

      else {
        console.log(`Match error!`)
        return "Match Error!"
      }
```

Comment: What question do you answer here? The questions are _"Return statement not printing to console?"_ and _"Does anyone know why this is?"_