Why does JavaScript while loop execute the iterator before consol.log
I would expect this code to print only up to 10. But it goes up to 12. I can modify the code to check for i<10 instead of i<=10. But I do not understand why the while loop goes on to print 12. I know my logic is correct.
I expect the below code to print up to 10. But it prints up to 12.
let i=0;
while (i<=10){
    console.log(i);
    i+=2;
}


Change your console.log() call to console.log("i is " + i); and try again. You're seeing what the browser prints after the loop is complete.

Thanks Pointy. I see that.  Why does it behave that way though? Shouldn’t console.log(i) be processed before i++ in that order?

@Pointy Lazy evaluation is only a thing with objects, not primitive values.

@deceze I wasn't talking about lazy evaluation, I was talking about browser console behavior. The loop as written did print 12, but it did so because that was the last evaluated statement value (or whatever the term for that is).

@Pointy Sounds like you're saying that console.log delays writing the value until after the loop has completed, thus logging the last value of i after the loop, even if the console.log statement is within the loop. Again: that's lazy evaluation by the console, and is only a thing with objects. Simple numbers will always log the value at the time of the console.log call; not the value of the variable whenever the console gets around to outputting the log.

@deceze well all I can say is that when I paste the original loop into the browser console, I see 12. When I modify the loop to make the console.log() calls more obvious, I still see 12, but it's printed without the added annotation.  Furthermore, if I add the line 17; as the last statement of the loop, the last thing printed is not 12, but 17.

@Pointy If anything, that's because the console implicitly outputs the value of the last statement as "return value" of the entire code. The console may even clearly distinguish between an implicit return value and logs (return values in my console have a left facing arrow, the console logs don't).

@deceze yes that's precisely what I was talking about. Adding the extra content to the log messages (which I think is a general good practice anyway) was only to demonstrate that 12 was coming from the console UI and not the console.log() statements.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined

The code works as expected. It doesn't print 12.
Using Code Snippet allows you to verify the code easily.


let i=0;
while (i<=10){
    console.log(i);
    i+=2;
}



Update based on comments from @Pointy and @deceze:
Some browsers can print a value of the declared variable after the loop, giving the impression that the loop prints 12.
For example:

This behavior is not related to the loop, and this can easily be verified by running the following:

Additionally, we can encapsulate the loop above (or any other code) into a function, and this will prevent 12 from being printed:

However, the browser will still output undefined as a return value of our code.

It does print 12 if you run it in the browser console.

@Pointy, you are right. I've updated the answer.
