# hoisting & closure - confusion

Tags: javascript, closures, hoisting

Hoisting:

```js
console.log(h)
var h = 1
```

This returns `undefined`, since the declaration is moved to the top, but the value is assigned after the `console.log()`, just like this:

```js
var h;
console.log(h)
h = 1
```

This now returns 1, which is don't understand, since it's supposed to be the exact same as above in my understanding

Closure: Why can `console.log()` as a function not access the global var `h` in the first example?

would be really happy, if sb could help me out here.
thank you!

Comment: This has nothing to do with closure - and your second example should indeed output `undefined`. Are you perhaps entering this code directly into the console, one after the other? Because if so then it is remembering the `h1 from the first snippet, which still holds the value `1`.

Comment: Added snippets to your question which clearly show the second script does not return 1.

Comment: "*This now returns 1*" - no, it does not? Running the snippet shows `undefined` as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed those 2 cases are similar, so what's happening here ?

I think you got a bit fooled by your console. Your console always log something when you execute a command anyways. You can read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880093/var-variable-returns-undefined) to get better acknowledges about what get returned by your console by default when you do `h=1;` and `var h=1;`.

**why can console.log() as a function not access the global var h in the first example?** :
It actually accesses the global `h` variable. But since there is not value assigned yet to h, well the console.log returns `undefined` which basically means that the `h` variable exists but the value it has is undefined. If it didn't find the `h` variable it would have returned instead an error saying that `h is not defined` which might be confusing, but is not the same as `undefined`

Comment: It does not access the global. The expression `h`, referencing the global, is evaluated when `log`is called, and the value is passed into the function by value.