# Why after call an expression with new, the console return undefined

Tags: javascript

After I create an object of primitive type on javascript console, it return undefine

for example

> var john = new String("John");

> undefined

But after continue to type

> john

> String {'John'}

Comment: Solution is here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880093/var-variable-returns-undefined

Answer (score 3):

When typing code into the console, what it "reads back" to you after you press enter is the **completion value** of the last statement.

Variable declarations [do not result in any completion value](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-variable-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation), so it reads back to you `undefined`.

But, a statement referencing an existing identifier will give you the value in the identifier - which, in this case, is a String object.

(But, keep in mind that there's almost no good reason to use the primitive constructors - better to use `var john = 'John';`)

Comment: Ahh. so what ever I type 'var a = ...' always return undefined, not relate to 'new' operator

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable and assign a value to it in console, it just sets the variable to the value you assigned it, it doesn't return anything.

So, if you open dev tools console and type:

```
let a = 1;
```

console will report `undefined`

if you then type `a` into console and press return, `1` will be displayed as the value returned by variable name a.

What you described is normal behaviour for the console.